# Deployment Component Error: No such column 'Single_Donor__c' on entity 'OpportunityLineItem'

Tags: apex, deployment

I am encountering below error when trying to deploy the a class. Below is error and class. I am not sure why i am getting this error inspite of having the custom field on entity.

error is

> No such column 'Single_Donor__c' on entity 'OpportunityLineItem'. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

```
if(quoteRecordtype=='Primary Cells Request'){ 
        olist = [Select Id, OpportunityId, SortOrder, PricebookEntryId, Quantity,ETA__c, 
        TotalPrice, UnitPrice, ListPrice, ServiceDate, Description, CreatedDate, 
        CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, Sales_Discount__c,opportunity.recordtype.name,
        Age__c,Anticoagulant__c,Cell_Isolation__c,Cells_per_Vial__c,Multiple_Donors__c,Single_Donor__c,Product_State__c,Desired_Cell_type__c,
        Donor_Blood_Type__c,End_Age__c,Ethnicity__c,Gender__c,Healthy_Tissue_Type__c,Product_Specifications__c,
        Medication_Constraints__c,Other_Info__c,Medication_Constraints_Other__c,Specific_Donor_s__c,HLA_Type__c,ADCC_Status__c,
       Other_Requirements__c,additional_testing__c,Spec_Description__c,Smoker__c,Unit_Cost_Price__c,Discount,CurrencyISOCode,
        IsDeleted , PricebookEntry.Name, PricebookEntry.Product2id,  Shipping_Cost__c, PricebookEntry.Product2.recordtype.name, PricebookEntry.Product2.Part_Id__c
        From OpportunityLineItem 
        where OpportunityId = :quote.Opportunity__c and product_sector__c = 'Primary Cells'];
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Error is clear. Single_Donor__c does not exist on opp line item

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add Single_Donor__c field to the changeset.

Comment: If field is there then check for the permission of the field

Comment: I have checked and performed all the 3 steps. 1. The field exists in production. 2. I copied and created the same fields in production. I have checked the permissions and FLS.

Comment: @TusharSharma, Don't the changeset validations happen in System Mode? Do they care of component permissions? I know test classes would fail. In this case it looks like component validation itself failed.

Comment: @Avinash Include sys admin profile in the changeset and make sure API name in the code is same as field API name

Comment: The field does not exist in the changes or in production then. Double and triple check the API name of the field. That error has not been the source of a bug, rather it IS correct and telling you to check again.

Comment: You guys were right. I must have deployed the fields instead of creating them. Thank you guys for your answers.

Comment: @Harvey - Added it as an answer so you can help the community and mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field does not exist in the changes or in production then.

**Double and triple check the API name of the field.**

That error has not been the source of a bug, rather it IS correct and telling you to check again.